# Compare a CPT post with a normal post

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to get the title of a CPT post (only from as specific post type) and then compare it to match with a regular post (of a specific category but it is not important!), that have the same title. In case the two title match (the slugs are the same! but of course different permalinks) I need two get the CPT post_ID to use in my template (the ACF field used there must be related to the a field group registered in the CPT type)

```
<?php the_field( "logo_attivita",[here the retrieved post_ID] );?>
```

Comment: Where do you need this to happen? In a specific template?

Comment: hello WebElaine I try to explain below what I need

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write something like this, but set in the functions of child theme I got php error:

I know there are bugs here but I say 'something like this'

```
$current_title = get_the_title(); 
$post = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attivita', 'posts_per_page'    => -1 ) ); 
function get_the_title( $post = 0 ) {
$post = get_post( $post );
$post_title = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
$post_id    = isset( $post->ID ) ? $post->ID : 0;
return apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_title, $post_id );
if ($current_title == $post_title) {   
$post_id == $cpt_id; }
else {
echo 'no CPT found!';
}    
}
```

The current_title  comes from the post of promo category and the cpt_id is the post_id of the CPT 'attivita' that has the same title of the current  post in prtomo category.  Getting the cpt_id I can use the fields groups of the cpt attivita and get the field content for each value set in cpt dashboard